# Determine whether 2 assoc arrays have the same content

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I'm trying to have a PHP function that compare 2 array and return true if they are identical.

Example:

```
assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)); // True
assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('b'=>2, 'a'=>1)); // True
assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array(1, 2)); // false
assertArrayEquals(array(2, 1), array(1, 2)); // false
```

Any idea ?

Edit:
Other tests cases:

```
assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3)); // false
assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3), array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)); // false
assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>0), array('a'=>'foo')); // false
```

Comment: Wouldn't `==` work fine enough for you?

Comment: Nop, as == only check for values ( like array_diff would ) Case #3 would pass.

Comment: @FMaz008, Case #3 does not pass with `==`. I tested it.

Comment: Well the 4 would pass then ( as the array_diff function isn't suppose to check the key association like array_diff_assoc )

Comment: Please check the manual ([Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)) before making assumptions:
"_$a == $b - Equality - TRUE if $a and $b have the **same key/value pairs**._" Example 4 _won't_ pass either as the key/value pairs are _not_ the same: `0 => 2, 1 => 1` vs `0 => 1, 1 => 2`.

Comment: @FMaz008, it does **NOT** check for the order, it checks only for the **key=>value** pairs! But `array(2, 1)` is the same as `array(0 => 2, 1 => 1)` because of the way the array is created. `==` itself does **not** check the order. _EDIT: this comment was a reply to a deleted comment._

Comment: @Czechnology Hum, I think you may be right... wait a sec.

Comment: @Czechnology please provide the answer in answer form. :)

Comment: @salathe, Ok sorry, was really meant just as a comment first :) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557584/determine-whether-2-assoc-arrays-have-the-same-content/5558101#5558101)

Comment: You should never ever use == in PHP. == is weird! Did you know "5.0" == "5" evals to true in PHP?? Triple equals to the max! (Also sorry I didn;t read the question carefully enough)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_diff_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

```
<?php

var_dump(assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2))); // True
var_dump(assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('b'=>2, 'a'=>1))); // True
var_dump(assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array(1, 2))); // false
var_dump(assertArrayEquals(array(2, 1), array(1, 2))); // false



function assertArrayEquals($a, $b){
  return count(array_diff_assoc($a,$b)) == 0 && count(array_diff_assoc($b,$a)) == 0;
}
```

http://codepad.org/YoZIGjBY

Comment: Seems like a good function, I'll unit test that and I'll be back :)

Comment: This pass and it should fail:
array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3)

Comment: Very true, let me rewrite it.

Comment: With the Charliepiga idea, I've come up with: return count(array_diff_assoc($a, $b)) == 0 && count(array_diff_assoc($b, $a)) == 0;, but maybe it's possible to do something better.

Answer (score 2):

check out http://php.net/array_diff and http://php.net/array_intersect

Or if all you wnna do is check for equality:

sort both arrays and check with === (or == if you're a scaredy kitty)

Comment: === will not assert the second case. == will only care about the values, same for array_diff/intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Use `==`.

[php Manual: Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> `$a == $b` - Equality - TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.

---

Example 4 won't pass as the key/value pairs are not the same:

`0 => 2, 1 => 1` vs `0 => 1, 1 => 2`.

---

*EDIT:*

If arrays contain different variable types, use

```
function assertArrayEquals($a, $b) {
  asort($a);
  asort($b);

  return $a === $b;
}
```

This will give expected results even for the example in the comment:

```
echo (int)assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),  array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2));     // true
echo (int)assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),  array('b'=>2, 'a'=>1));     // true
echo (int)assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),  array(1, 2));               // false
echo (int)assertArrayEquals(array(2, 1),            array(1, 2));               // false
echo (int)assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>0,'b'=>1),   array('a'=>'cake','b'=>1)); // false
echo (int)assertArrayEquals(array('a'=>'0','b'=>1), array('a'=>'cake','b'=>1)); // false
```

Comment: `array('a'=>0,'b'=>1) == array('a'=>'cake','b'=>1)` gives incorrect result for FMaz008's needs.

Comment: For that test case, I would expect false, not true... :(

Comment: Yes that will happen because `0=='cake'`. On the other hand `array('a'=>'0','b'=>1) == array('a'=>'cake','b'=>1)` would return false (note the quotes around zero). But you could sort and compare using `===` - see my editted answer.

Comment: @salathe, depends on the application. I guess in most applications the values with the same keys would probably have the same type. If not, the later solution is better...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to make sure the arrays have the same key/value pairs (strictly typed) but not necessarily in the same order. So, make the orders consistent and strictly compare them.

```
function assertArrayEquals($a, $b)
{
    ksort($a); ksort($b);
    return ($a === $b);
}
```

---

By way of testing,

```
testAssertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),         array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),         true);
testAssertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),         array('b'=>2, 'a'=>1),         true);
testAssertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),         array(1, 2),                   false);
testAssertArrayEquals(array(2, 1),                   array(1, 2),                   false);
testAssertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),         array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3), false);
testAssertArrayEquals(array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3), array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2),         false);
testAssertArrayEquals(array('a'=>0,'b'=>1),          array('a'=>'cake','b'=>1),     false); // Extra

function testAssertArrayEquals($a, $b, $expected)
{
    $result = assertArrayEquals($a, $b);
    echo "Got " . var_export($result,1) . " expected " . var_export($expected,1) . PHP_EOL;
}

// Got true expected true
// Got true expected true
// Got false expected false
// Got false expected false
// Got false expected false
// Got false expected false
// Got false expected false
```

---

I would also advise picking a better function name, your current choice is not going to do you any favours in the long run!

Answer (score 0):

```
function assertArrayEquals($array1, $array2) {
  return !array_diff($array1, $array2) and !array_diff($array2, $array1);
}
```

Basically we use [array_diff()](http://php.net/array_diff) to check whatever there are any difference between the two given array. If there are not, then they are equal.

Despite this clean form, you could use the simple `==` to compare the two array.
Here's some tested samples:

```
echo (array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2) == array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2)) ? 'true' : 'false'; // true
echo (array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2) == array('b'=>2, 'a'=>1)) ? 'true' : 'false'; // true
echo (array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2) == array(1, 2)) ? 'true' : 'false'; // false
echo (array(2, 1) == array(1, 2)) ? 'true' : 'false'; // false
```

This script output: `truetruefalsefalse`;

Comment: Fail to assert that array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2), array('b'=>1, 'a'=>2) is false.

Comment: It should have been false, as the values of the key have been swapped.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function for this.

```
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

$result will return everything that is different in the arrays.  If they are the same it will return nothing.

Comment: Doesn't take care of the keys.